# How to clear sent values from Coroutine's Channel?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.channels

Lets say I've sent a few values in a channel,

```
val channel = Channel<Int>()
launch {
    for (x in 1..5) channel.send(x * x)
}
```

How can I "clear" them? Meaning consume them without using them

Comment: not sure if this can help but I though I should give you some [hint](https://medium.com/@elizarov/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761)

Comment: I feel like wanting to clear the channel is a bit of a code smell... I feel like it is almost like wanting to cancel the call of a function you have already called. Can you give more context?

Comment: I would look at either implementing something like an expiry  on each message, or a way of setting some counter for each message and then controlling some greater than offset for your consumer. Messages that are too old or have a sequence less than the offset get dropped instead of processed.

Comment: General note: channels are single-consumer, so you shouldn't try to find a way to get in from the side and take out messages. The dedicated consumer should be the only one to take them and it should decide when not to take any action.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. l'll rethink the approach, I'll probably set an expiry or something alike to messages (as @Laurence said) and will have the consumer be the dedicated consumer (as @Marko) said

Comment: I had similar issue, trying to clean my channel before starting up a new communication, making sure I don't have leftovers from the previous one. So I realised that myChannel.close() can clean it and then I rebuilt a new one. This way the previous channel got canceled immediately.